# How to change email template on openedx

Tags: openedx, edx

As a student recover the password, then received an email that the password has changed,

i want to customized the content but can not find the template

it should be in this folder
/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/emails

but still can not find the email template for password recovery email

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in these folders.

```
common/templates/student/edx_ace/passwordreset/email/body.html
common/templates/student/edx_ace/accountrecovery/email/body.txt
```

And you can add custom emails in your custom theme folder

```
lms/templates/emails
```

Comment: however the logo seems can not be edited from body.html, where can i edit the logo in the email? thanks in advance

Comment: You can add/extend your header.

Comment: yes, i found code  extends ace_common/edx_ace/common/base_body.html,  where can i find such directory?